# cannot find symbol ds.setMaxActive(MAX_ACTIVE);

Tags: java, connection, database-connection, datasource, dbcp

I am trying to Configure Oracle DataSource Using Commons DBCP but its throwing subject error

I am working on CentOS

```
 private String driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ;
 private String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@164.173.28.18:1521:XE";
 private String userName="username";
 private String password="password";
 private static int MAX_ACTIVE= 10;
 private BasicDataSource ds = null;

 public void init() throws SQLException{
  ds = new BasicDataSource();
  ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
  ds.setPassword(password);
  ds.setUsername(userName);
  ds.setUrl(url);
  ds.setMaxActive(MAX_ACTIVE);
  //check connections
  ds.getConnection();  
 }


 public Connection getOracleConnection() throws SQLException{
  return ds.getConnection();
 }
```

How can I fix

```
DB.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
  ds.setMaxActive(MAX_ACTIVE);                                                                                              ^
  symbol:   method setMaxActive(int)
  location: variable ds of type BasicDataSource
1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously, your datasource class doesn't support [maxactive](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#setMaxActive(int)).

you need check your library version.

Comment: Its mean I remove it from my code or replace it with some other function. Please advise

Comment: yeah. you can remove it for now. As it is just a parameter. To see if it works or not.